# Is there an advantage to Featurizing a view, over using Views' export?

Tags: views, features, importing-exporting

I've created a View in Drupal 6 with Views 2. If I want to get this view from my dev site to production, is there a compelling advantage offered by using Features over using the built-in Views export?

Comment: You might also want to check out [Configuration](http://drupal.org/project/configuration), Features doesn't hold a candle to it for config management in my opinion

Comment: That looks really useful, but I'm using Drupal 6.

Comment: Ah that's a shame. Features is still great for what it is though. Configuration is a back-port of the ongoing config effort in Drupal 8 so it's a lot more lightweight and focused than features, but for Drupal 6 Features is probably a better option than manually exporting/importing...at least your view can live in code and the changes can be tracked in version control

Comment: Changes living in code means they'll break when the site is upgraded to Drupal 7, though, right?

Comment: @Clive Whilst we're mentioning config management, I'm just gonna leave this here:  [Configuration builder](http://drupal.org/project/config_builder).

Comment: @beth To be fair, a lot of things will probably break/not work as expected if upgrading from D6 to D7 anyway.  There's a post [here](http://drupal.org/node/1014522) about upgrading Features from D6 to D7.  Consensus sees to be *consolidate features into database prior to core upgrade*

Comment: @beth Yeah that's true...as I understand it you'd be expected to manually update all of your feature modules as part of the larger upgrade process anyway, which would eliminate that problem. But knowing the site might be upgraded at some point changes the whole config management dynamic a bit anyway

Comment: @Chapabu It still amazes me how many good modules I've never even heard of. Thanks!

Comment: I think that Chapabu and Clive should write up alternate answers based on Configuration and Configuration Builder and outline why they may be better solutions that Features for this case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For *a single* View, there is no difference in functionality really. The view will be the same regardless.

I use [Features](http://drupal.org/project/features) anyway because it's makes it more conventient to organize multiple pieces of configuration into "features". I'm not aware that ctools offers any easy way of doing "This view with that panel and those three dependencies in one module". That is what features adds on top of [Ctools](http://drupal.org/project/ctools).

It's worth mentioning that the [Configuration](http://drupal.org/project/configuration) module is an useful alternative that largely makes the configuration tracking easier. If you don't care about the features aspect of features, take it for a spin. (Thanks [Clive](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/2800/clive) for pointing this out)